# XSLT when/otherwise output more than once

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some XSLT that should output a single piece of PLAIN text dependent on values within the input XML document.

I have a template-match clause which filters out SIStatusHistory nodes when a 'Status' value within that node has a value of 'SRequested' OR 'SCreated'. I don't want those nodes to be evaluated.

EDIT:

For example the sub node list:

```
 <SIHistories>
        <SIStatusHistory>
            <Created>2019-09-10T12:55:45.613</Created>
            <SIStat>
                <ServiceInstanceStatusId>5</ServiceInstanceStatusId>
                <Status>SRequested</Status>
            </SIStat>
        </SIStatusHistory>
        <SIStatusHistory>
            <Created>2019-09-10T13:06:37.153</Created>
            <SIStat>
                <ServiceInstanceStatusId>5</ServiceInstanceStatusId>
                <Status>SRejected</Status>
            </SIStat>
        </SIStatusHistory>
        <SIStatusHistory>
            <Created>2019-09-10T15:14:56.28</Created>
            <SIStat>
                <ServiceInstanceStatusId>5</ServiceInstanceStatusId>
                <Status>SRequested</Status>
            </SIStat>
        </SIStatusHistory>
    </SIHistories>
```

Should be pared down to:

```
 <SIHistories>      
        <SIStatusHistory>
            <Created>2019-09-10T13:06:37.153</Created>
            <SIStat>
                <ServiceInstanceStatusId>5</ServiceInstanceStatusId>
                <Status>SRejected</Status>
            </SIStat>
        </SIStatusHistory>
    </SIHistories>
```

...and then evaluated for Status='SRejected'

When the first SIStatusHistory node has a Status of 'SRejected' OR RAddress = 'No' this should be output:

"CheckQueue"

Otherwise, output:

"CompQueue"

The Issue I am having is that the XSLT seems to be executing multiple times for each sub-node in my template-match clause.

So (for example) instead of

CompQueue

I'm getting the output:

"CompQueueCompQueue"

Any ideas?

Input XML:

```
<SForm xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://test/p/s/types">
<SFID>00000</SFID>
<SID>00000</SID>
<FData>
    <FPH>
        <RAddress>No</RAddress>
        <FaultDescription>Text</FaultDescription>
        <Channel>P</Channel>
        <Customer/>
    </FPH>
    <ApplicantExt>
        <HasCommercialUse>Yes</HasCommercialUse>
    </ApplicantExt>
</FData>
<SIFormCounters />
<CompDate>2019-09-10T13:05:18.883</CompDate>
<SIHistories>
    <SIStatusHistory>
        <Created>2019-09-10T12:55:45.613</Created>
        <SIStat>
            <ServiceInstanceStatusId>5</ServiceInstanceStatusId>
            <Status>SRequested</Status>
        </SIStat>
    </SIStatusHistory>
    <SIStatusHistory>
        <Created>2019-09-10T13:06:37.153</Created>
        <SIStat>
            <ServiceInstanceStatusId>5</ServiceInstanceStatusId>
            <Status>SRejected</Status>
        </SIStat>
    </SIStatusHistory>
    <SIStatusHistory>
        <Created>2019-09-10T15:14:56.28</Created>
        <SIStat>
            <ServiceInstanceStatusId>5</ServiceInstanceStatusId>
            <Status>SRequested</Status>
        </SIStat>
    </SIStatusHistory>
</SIHistories>
```

XSLT:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:pst="http://test/p/s/types" exclude-result-prefixes="pst" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" />
 <xsl:template match="text()" />
  <xsl:template match="pst:SForm/pst:SIHistories/pst:SIStatusHistory[pst:SIStat/pst:Status='SCreated' or pst:SIStat/pst:Status='SRequested']">
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="pst:SIHistories/pst:SIStatusHistory[1]/pst:SIStat/pst:Status = 'SRejected'">
        <xsl:text>CheckQueue</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="pst:FormData/pst:FPH/pst:RAddress = 'No'">
        <xsl:text>CheckQueue</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>CompQueue</xsl:text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please post desired output which will illustrate the hard to read explanation at the top.

Comment: Desired output is as described - the plain text: CheckQueue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need that to remove all nodes that have the value SCreated and SRequested, before we evaluate if the first node is SRejected.

I believe that could be implemented as:

```
<xsl:template match="SIHistories">
    <xsl:variable name="first-status" select="SIStatusHistory[not(SIStat/Status='SCreated' or SIStat/Status='SRequested')][1]/SIStat/Status" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$first-status='SRejected'">CheckQueue</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>CompQueue</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Bingo. This works - and it makes sense now. I just had to add the namespaces in and add the check on the RAddress field back into the when-otherwise and it functions as needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there are two elements for your template match with condition *pst:Status='SRequested'*. Since you intend to check the first, adjust template using `position()=1` on first node. Additionally, you need to invoke `ancestor::*` or walk up the tree to check the *FData* condition

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:pst="http://test/p/s/types" 
                exclude-result-prefixes="pst" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" />
    <xsl:template match="text()" />

    <xsl:template match="pst:SForm/pst:SIHistories/pst:SIStatusHistory[position()=1 and (pst:SIStat/pst:Status='SCreated' or pst:SIStat/pst:Status='SRequested')]">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="pst:SIHistories/pst:SIStatusHistory[1]/pst:SIStat/pst:Status = 'SRejected'">
            <xsl:text>CheckQueue</xsl:text>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="ancestor::pst:SForm/pst:FData/pst:FPH/pst:RAddress = 'No'">
            <xsl:text>CheckQueue</xsl:text>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>CompQueue</xsl:text>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The only issue here is that I think that having postion()=1 in the template match call means it is only applying the removal of the two values SRequested and SCreated to the first node. Whereas I need that to remove all nodes that have the value SCreated and SRequested, before we evaluate if the first node is SRejected.